# MtGox websockets vs HTTP - which is more real-time?

Tags: mtgox

MtGox currently offers both a websockets and HTTP API services. According to the documentation the HTTP service caches prices for 10sec but there is no clarification (that I can find) that details the real-time guarantees of the streaming services?

Which would be expected to be closest to real-time?

Answer (score 1):

You would expect websockets to be more real-time because it is designed as an upgrade to HTTP to enable live streaming and real-time services.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any direct experience of this?